# Batch file - How to read multiple .txt file that in a folder?

Tags: batch-file

Currently I just success to read from one .txt file only. Here is my code.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_20140331_1509_CW52.txt) do SET e=%%a
```

My question is I got one folder contain of many .txt file, however above code only read specified .txt file. Any changes that I need to made so that it can loop through all the .txt files?

Example of .txt file name.

```
log_DP_20140331_1324_CW52.txt
log_DP_20345692_1234_CW51.txt
log_DP_21234324_2134_CW50.txt
```

FYI, folder contains more than 3 .txt files.
Any guidance ,answer or similar post to share?

Thanks for viewing, comments and answers.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can just say `in (C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt)` and it will load them all.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hello, I tried this `for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt) do SET e=%%a` and I can't get even one txt file =(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have how to iterate over a file content. The only you need is to iterate over the file list and read the content of each file. So

```
for %%x in (C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt
) do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~fx") do .....
```

Where `%%x` holds a reference to each file in the set and `%%~fx` is the full path to the file. To avoid problems with possible spaces in filenames, i have quoted it `"%%~fx"`, so, to indicate to `for /f` comand that it is not a string but a file, `usebackq` has been included in the `for` options string

Comment: Hi MC, thanks for the clear answer! This is working. However I met another problem that is when I `....("%%~fx") do set e=%%a` I always get the last file variable only. Eg. The 1st file variable - `Error` and the 2nd file variable `Success`. I always get the 2nd file variable which is `Success` when ever I `do set e=%%a`. Why is this happen? I need both variable so that I can perform IF statement. Please help!

Comment: If you need help to use files in the loop then they can be accessed different ways and the easiest way depends on precisely what you want to do.  Edit your question to include more detail.

Comment: @user2709555, if all you do is `set var=value`, on each iteration the value is overwritten. From your comment, i can not see clear enough what your needs are. Can you post another question with a sample of your files, what are the requirements, what you get and what you should get? Comments are too limited to handle all this.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Noted. I will open new post to answer this question. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hi MC, here is my new post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799774/batch-file-how-to-get-a-keyword-and-perform-action-if-once-the-keyword-detec)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) function. You can put the code you have into the body of the [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) loop. Check out [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/) it is a great resource for a number of scripting languages.