# Batch File - How to get a Keyword and perform action (IF) once the keyword detected while looping through multiple text files?

Tags: batch-file

I trying to perform action (IF statement) when looping through multiple text files( read line by line of text file) inside a folder by using the Keyword inside the text file. I able to loop through multiple text files. However I only get the last text file Keyword. I do not know why is this happening. My expected result is that I able to get every keyword inside the text file, while the Keyword is detected it will perform the IF statement, after IF statement then it will continue to loop through other text file and looking for another keyword.

Eg. Log_DP_123.txt content.

```
ERROR-D12345678
```

Eg. Log_DP_124.txt content.

```
DisConnected
```

My code:

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt
) do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~fx") do SET e=%%a
echo %e%
SET x=%e%
SET s=!x:~0,5!
SET date=!x:~6,14!
SET !d!
SET !s!
pause
IF "%s%" == "DisCo" (
(
echo disconnected
)
IF "%s%" == "ERROR" (
echo Sucess
echo %s%
echo %date%
)
)>C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\Mohit_Task\AutomatedScript\COB\sucess.txt

pause
```

Any changes that I need to make to meet my expected result?

Expected result - In sucess.txt it will list all the echo's.
Eg. Contents inside sucess.txt.

```
Sucess
Error
12345678
disconnected
```

Thanks for viewing, comments and answers.

Although the answer that I accepted is different from Post. But I found out the method that Aacini provide is simple, easy understanding and very useful to me. So I accepted that answer. P.s. If you looking for this post answer, it should be Dbenham answer!

Comment: which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: @blueberryfields Hi, I am using Windows.

Comment: which version of windows?

Comment: @blueberryfields windows 7.

Comment: Please, show your expected results...

Comment: See the edit in my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid I don't understand what your code tries to do. When you ask for help, you always should *explain in words* what the code is supposed to do; otherwise, how we could help you? For example, based on your code it seems that you don't care *in which file* the keywords appear (you never show the value of `%%x`).

Anyway, if you want to search several files looking for lines that start in "DisCo" or "ERROR" strings, then the following command do that:

```
findstr /B "DisCo ERROR" C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt
```

This command show the matching lines with some additional information (like the name of the file), but you may process these lines with a `for` command taking the colon as delimiter.

I hope it helps...

**EDIT**

I taken previous `findstr` command and inserted it in your code, but modified it accordingly:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%e in ('findstr /B "DisCo ERROR" log_DP_*.txt') do (
   REM echo %%e
   SET x=%%e
   SET s=!x:~0,5!
   SET ddate=!x:~7,14!
   IF "!s!" == "DisCo" (
      echo disconnected
   ) else (
      echo Sucess
      echo !s!
      echo !ddate!
   )
)
```

Eg. Log_DP_123.txt content:

```
Any other line
ERROR-D12345678
Any other line
```

Eg. Log_DP_124.txt content:

```
Any other line
Any other line
DisConnected
Any other line
```

Output:

```
Sucess
ERROR
12345678
disconnected
```

Comment: +1, Very different result, but a good guess as to a simple solution that likely would be useful to the OP.

Comment: @dbenham You are right! It is very useful and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed - the parentheses appear unbalanced. This can lead to strange problems. Indentation is a good way to perform a visual check; one or two spaces to indent each time you open a new pair of parentheses and line up the closing parenthesis with the keyword (like `for`) that caused a pair to be opened.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)` in `delayedexpansion` mode (which you have invoked) then `%var%` is resolved to the value of the variable **at the time the outermost for is parsed**. `!var!` is resolved to the **run-time** value, that is, its current value as it changes through the block.

So within the block, `%e%` will mean "the original value of `e`" - that is, not set and hence empty. Replace that with `!e!` to get the run-time value that you expect.

And the `set !s!` which you've bravely used to attempt to debug will be resolved to `set Disco` (or would if `s` was at that time set to `Disco`). `SET` shows the run-time value of any variable matching or commencing with the argument it's given - so if `s` is set to `Disco`, then `set !s!` will show the values of environment variables starting `Disco` whereas `set s` would show all environment variables starting `s`.

Next little problem - an probably more for future reference - `DATE` is a magic value which returns the current date. If you override it as yu've done by setting it to a value, then *THAT* value will be returned.

Finally - please use meaningful names. Sure, `s` and `e` are easy to type, but it's very easy to get `%e%` confused with `%%e` - especially when concatenating strings.

Comment: Thanks for the teaching and advice.. I will slowly understand what you trying to say due to I m still new in batch programming. I will try make the changes. Thanks!!

Comment: +1, However, the parentheses are not unbalanced. But the logic is certainly wrong in that only the last line of last file is tested. And addition of parentheses to correctly test all lines of all files will fail for the reasons you stated.

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are misplaced. I think you probably mean to do this:

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt) DO (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~fx") DO (
        SET e=%%a
        echo %e%
        SET x=%e%
        SET s=!x:~0,5!
        SET date=!x:~6,14!
        SET !d!
        SET !s!
        pause
        IF "%s%" == "DisCo" (
            echo disconnected
        )
        IF "%s%" == "ERROR" (
            echo Sucess
            echo %s%
            echo %date%
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: hmm, I only keep get s=`~0,5`. Can't get `DisCo` or `ERROR`.

Comment: This cannot work as written because `%e%` and `%s%` will expand to the value that existed prior to the start of the loop. Delayed expansion would need to be used to get the current value.

Answer (score 1):

Magoo makes excellent points in his answer, so I won't bother repeating them.

I believe the following is the logic that you were attempting to achieve. Note that indenting lines within parentheses makes the logic much easier to follow.

The `echo(!part2!` is a safe way to print out the value of a variable, even if the value is empty or contains only spaces. It looks like unbalanced parentheses, but it is not. A simple `echo !part2!` would print out `ECHO is off.` if the value is empty or spaces only.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  for %%x in (
    C:\test\Scriptlogs\COB\log_DP_*.txt
  ) do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~fx") do (
    set "str=%%a"
    set "part1=!str:~0,5!"
    set "part2=!str:~6,14!"
    ( REM Presumably, these are debug statements that should
      REM not be included in the output file.
      REM So the output is directed to stderr
        echo str=!str!
        echo part1=!part1!
        echo part2=!part2!
    )>&2
    if "!part1!" == "DisCo" echo diconnected
    if "!part1!" == "ERROR" (
      echo Sucess
      echo(!part1!
      echo(!part2!
    )
  )
)>"C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\Mohit_Task\AutomatedScript\COB\sucess.txt"
```

Comment: Hi, the result end up I get only is "diconnected" in the sucess.txt. Anyway, thanks for your time and teaching!

Comment: @user2709555 - Oops, sorry about that. That is a result of not testing on my part. I forgot to add a critical set of parentheses around the entire outer FOR statement so that a single redirection works against all iterations. My original code was overwriting the output file with each iteration, so only the last line was kept. All fixed now.